# usage of cdi's in a ejb project without jsf

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, cdi

I am learning javaEE and I read somewhere about the main usage of cdi's was back then first in jsf-managed beans with annotations like @requestscope, @applicationscope, etc.. now in newer javaEE versions the cdi got available everywhere (even in ejb beans) so the question is, how do I have to annotate a class which shall be injected inside my local stateless ejb? I am asking this because the annotations like @RequestScope and all those are from jsf but I am not using jsf. Is @Default enough since its marked as default anyway? Is @Dependent better choice?

```
@Stateless
public class FooEjb{
@Inject Bar b;
}

// what annotation to put here?
public class Bar {
...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you don't need JSF to use CDI in JavaEE.

If you are using CDI without using JSF, use the scope annotations from the [`javax.enterprise.context`](https://docs.jboss.org/cdi/api/1.0-SP1/javax/enterprise/context/) package.

`@Default` is a [qualifier](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbck.html) which as the name suggests the default qualifier. If you have multiple implementations/instances of the same class in your container, then you can use qualifiers to distinguish.

`@Dependent` is a [scope](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbbk.html) which is the default scope. This means it will depend on the scope of the class it's injected in. A new instance of a `@Dependent` class will be injected every time a new instance of the class in which it is injected is created.

To enable CDI you need to put a [`beans.xml`](https://gist.github.com/sejersbol/845053) file in `WEB-INF` directory of your web project or `META-INF` directory of your EAR or EJB project.

Comment: That means every bean is automatically '@Default' and '@Dependent'? If I would have 3 different impl of my bean then there would be 3 times '@Default' therefore I should use '@Alternative', right?

Comment: @devhedgehog: Yes every bean in the container is `@Default` and `@Dependent` unless declared otherwise. If you have two implementations then `@Alternative` would be fine, however for more than two you can write your own `@Qualifiers`. https://dzone.com/articles/define-cdi-qualifier

Comment: Ok I understand that so far. Now the question is how to I inject a ejb stateless class without using "@EJB"?

Comment: If it's a local interface, you can simply do `@Inject`.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [java ee documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/cdi-basic005.htm#GIZKS), no annotation is required in your case. A simple POJO is an injectable bean and receive the `@Default` annotation. No need to use JSF.

Comment: I guess those pojos are by default market as "@Default" and "@Dependent" or am I wrong?

Comment: Ok so far so clear but now the question is how do I inject a stateless ejb without using the ´@EJB´ annotation